# Else not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have an whole page overlay, when mega menu is active. I am trying something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
$("div").click(function(){
   if ( $('.mega-menu-item').is('.mega-toggle-on') ) {
       $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
   }
   else {
    $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
   }
});

});
```

I got the "if" to work, however there is something wrong with the "else", since the div keeps showing once the div has not .mega-toggle-on anymore.

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be `hasClass('mega-toggle-on')` instead of `is`?

Comment: show us ur dom structure i thing ur calling it in a wrong way and should use hasClass dom 1st ??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if ( $('.mega-menu-item').is('.mega-toggle-on') ) {
    $('#twc-page-overlay').show();
}
else {
    $('#twc-page-overlay').hide();
}
```

You could simply do:

```
if ( $('.mega-menu-item').hasClass('mega-toggle-on') ) {
    $('#twc-page-overlay').toggleClass('show');
}
```

css:

```
#twc-page-overlay {
    display: none;
}

.show { 
    display: block; 
}
```

As you can see, `#twc-page-overlay` is hidden by default. When the toggle is triggered, it is shown.

Comment: add you mean with "add some logic here" ? Like display?

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer on how it would look please?

Comment: Edited. Also changed `is` to `hasClass`

Comment: Still not working. The addition of the class on #twc-page-overlay is working, but it doesnt show the name of the class (.show) like this: <div id="twc-page-overlay" class=""></div>

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? Cause this could possible be a CSS issue. If you are trying to overlay something, display block is probably not what you want.

Comment: Once the mega menu is active (.mega-menu-item has .mega-toggle-on) display an overlay (#twc-page-overlay) thru the rest of the site

Comment: Do you also see that, the function is adding class.. but doesnt show the name (.show) of the class.

Comment: I don't see the problem on the page you provide. With mega menu has `mega-toggle-on` it displays an overlay, and the Story menu, without `mega-toggle-on`, it does not display overlay, it display your story. I think it worked properly

Comment: I think Mr Neo is right.. try to look into your CSS. Maybe instead of hide/show, you can have like `background: transparent` and `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` or something. Display none/block may give undesired reuslts here.

Comment: Try `addClass`, tell me how that goes.

Comment: Yes, adds the class! but now it doesnt toggle

Comment: Try an else block now. Basically your original statement, instead now using `addClass` and `removeClass` instead of `show` and `hide`.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$("div").click(function(){
  if ( $('.mega-menu-item').hasClass('mega-toggle-on') ) {
    $('#twc-page-overlay').addClass('show');
}

else {
 $('#twc-page-overlay').removeClass('show');
}

});

});